# How to automatically start a service when running a docker container?

Tags: docker

I have a Dockerfile to install MySQL server in a container, which I then start like this:

```
sudo docker run -t -i 09d18b9a12be /bin/bash
```

But the MySQL service does not start automatically, I have to manually run (from within the container):

```
service mysql start
```

How do I automatically start the MySQL service when I run the docker container?

Comment: no, for one simple service, supervisor is not needed, it makes complicated for start user

Comment: you might want to copy the dockerfile here instead of linking to a file that no longer exists

Comment: The docker article on supervisord is now here: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/    I used the && tail command to get my service to work - but needed to add "--cap-add SYS_PTRACE" to the docker run command.

Comment: I'm surprised this thread gets >200 upvotes. It does not even contains the mentioned Dockerfile but a link to non existing file. It should be a part of this thread.

Answer (score 269, accepted):

First, there is a **problem** in your `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN service mysql restart && /tmp/setup.sh
```

Docker images do not save running processes. Therefore, your `RUN` command executes only  during `docker build` phase and stops after the build is completed.  Instead, you need to specify the command when the container is started using the `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` commands like below:

```
CMD mysql start
```

Secondly, the docker container needs a process (last command) to keep running, otherwise the container will exit/stop. Therefore, the normal `service mysql start` command cannot be used directly in the Dockerfile.

### Solution

There are three typical ways to keep the process running:

- Using `service` command and append non-end command after that like `tail -F`

  ```
  CMD service mysql start && tail -F /var/log/mysql/error.log
  ```

This is often preferred when you have a single service running as it makes the outputted log accessible to docker.

- Or use foreground command to do this

  ```
  CMD /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
  ```

This works only if there is a script like `mysqld_safe`.

- Or wrap your scripts into `start.sh` and put this in end

  ```
  CMD /start.sh
  ```

This is best if the command must perform a series of steps, again, `/start.sh` should stay running.

### Note

For the beginner using `supervisord` is not recommended. Honestly, it is overkill.  It is much better to use single service / single command for the container.

BTW: please check https://registry.hub.docker.com for existing mysql docker images for reference

Comment: How would you restart the service once started in the docker container?

Comment: @KarlMorrison `docker exec -it <CONTAINER NAME> mysql /etc/init.d/mysqld restart`

Comment: I would not recommend tail'ing MySQL's error log to determine if the database is running or not. 

In most mysqld setups, the server will recover from soe errors and in the process of doing this the error log will be closed and then reopened. I am also unsure that your tail -F will work out for you in all or even some cases.

Comment: I am not sure why, but the first solution option works fine for service script. When you do not use tail, it will fail, even though service is started(at least for tomcat7 service). With tail it works.

For both cases you need to use switch cap_add(--cap-add SYS_PTRACE for run) with at least SYS_PTRACE

Comment: https://registry.hub.docker.com will be redirected to https://hub.docker.com/ no relevant information on that page.

Comment: So when a Docker Container is run the normal services that are registered to start via systemctl do not run?

Comment: no, see more in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46800594/start-service-using-systemctl-inside-docker-conatiner

Comment: Coolest answer, saved me purchasing Udemy coarse.

Answer (score 97):

In your `Dockerfile`, add at the last line

```
ENTRYPOINT service ssh restart && bash
```

It works for me

And this is the result:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/vagrant/docker/add# docker run -i -t ubuntu
 * Restarting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd   [ OK ]                                                                      
root@dccc354e422e:~# service ssh status
 * sshd is running
```

Comment: this is nice but I think you can't have a detached container this way.

Comment: This worked great for me. I was having trouble getting Nginx 1.8 to auto start. You may find adding the following helpful:

RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log
RUN ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

Comment: Are there any drawbacks to this solution?

Comment: Starting Bash finally is a bad idea when you want to stop your services gracefully, because in this way the docker contaienr cannot be stopped by `docker stop` or `docker restart` gracefully, just it can be killed.

Comment: I was working  on packer to create docker images and this seems to fix my issue with the conaitner in the packer file. 
"changes": [
"ENTRYPOINT service nginx start && /bin/bash"
]

Comment: Using "bash" as the final command not worked but using "tail -d /var/log/mysql/error.log" works fine. Thank you and @larry-cai

Answer (score 19):

Simple! Add at the end of dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT service mysql start && /bin/bash
```

Comment: This is the best answer that solves my current Docker Container issue: `Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d`, without `&& /bin/bash` the service will stop immediately

Answer (score 13):

There's another way to do it that I've always found to be more readable.

Say that you want to start rabbitmq and mongodb when you run it then your `CMD` would look something like this:

```
CMD /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server start && \
    /etc/init.d/mongod start
```

Since you can have only one `CMD` per `Dockerfile` the trick is to concatenate all instructions with `&&` and then use `\` for each command to start a new line.

If you end up adding to many of those I suggest you put all your commands in a script file and start it like [@larry-cai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25150809/3621724) suggested:

```
CMD /start.sh
```

Answer (score 7):

This not works `CMD  service mysql start && /bin/bash`

This not works `CMD service mysql start ; /bin/bash ;`

-- i guess interactive mode would not support foreground.

This works !!  `CMD service nginx start ; while true ; do sleep 100; done;`

This works !!  `CMD service nginx start && tail -F /var/log/nginx/access.log`

beware you should using `docker run  -p 80:80 nginx_bash` without command parameter.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I have a PHP web application being served by Apache2 within the docker container that connects to a MYSQL backend database. Larry Cai's solution worked with minor modifications. I created a `entrypoint.sh` file within which I am managing my services. I think creating an `entrypoint.sh` when you have more than one command to execute when your container starts up is a cleaner way to bootstrap docker.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

echo "Starting the mysql daemon"
service mysql start

echo "navigating to volume /var/www"
cd /var/www
echo "Creating soft link"
ln -s /opt/mysite mysite

a2enmod headers
service apache2 restart

a2ensite mysite.conf
a2dissite 000-default.conf
service apache2 reload

if [ -z "$1" ]
then
    exec "/usr/sbin/apache2 -D -foreground"
else
    exec "$1"
fi
```

Comment: Just put it alongside your Dockerfile. Then in your Dockerfile you should have an instruction that copies this file to the desired location. Then you point the `ENTRYPOINT ['your location']` instruction to the script file. Remember to set the execute permissions on your script though. `COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh RUN chmod 755 /entrypoint.sh 
 ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]`. In this example, i copied my entry point to root directory in the docker container.

Comment: where is Dockerfile?

Answer (score 5):

I add the following code to /root/.bashrc to run the code only once,

Please commit the container to the image before run this script, otherwise the 'docker_services' file will be created in the images and no service will be run.

```
if [ ! -e /var/run/docker_services ]; then
    echo "Starting services"
    service mysql start
    service ssh start
    service nginx start
    touch /var/run/docker_services
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem when I want to automatically start ssh service.
I found that append

```
/etc/init.d/ssh start
```

to

```
~/.bashrc
```

can resolve it ,but only you open it with bash will do.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I automatically start the MySQL service whenever the docker container runs.

On my case, I need to run not just MySQL but also PHP, Nginx and Memcached

I have the following lines in Dockerfile

```
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 3306
CMD service mysql start && service php-fpm start && nginx -g 'daemon off;' && service memcached start && bash
```

Adding **&& bash** would keep Nginx, MySQL, PHP and Memcached running within the container.

Answer (score 2):

```
ENTRYPOINT name-service
```

Inside your Dockerfile

Example:

```
ENTRYPOINT mysqld_explorer
```

***/etc/systemd/system/mysqld_explorer.service***

Answer (score 1):

```
docker export -o <nameOfContainer>.tar <nameOfContainer>
```

Might need to prune the existing container using docker prune ...

Import with required modifications:

```
cat <nameOfContainer>.tar | docker import -c "ENTRYPOINT service mysql start && /bin/bash" - <nameOfContainer>
```

Run the container for example with always restart option to make sure it will auto resume after host/daemon recycle:

```
docker run -d -t -i --restart always --name <nameOfContainer> <nameOfContainer> /bin/bash
```

Side note:
In my opinion reasonable is to start only cron service leaving container as clean as possible then just modify crontab or cron.hourly, .daily etc... with corresponding checkup/monitoring scripts. Reason is You rely only on one daemon and in case of changes it is easier with ansible or puppet to redistribute cron scripts instead of track services that start at boot.

Answer (score 0):

The following documentation from the Docker website shows how to implement an SSH service in a docker container. It should be easily adaptable for your service:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/

A variation on this question has also been asked here:

- [Start sshd automatically with docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886470/start-sshd-automatically-with-docker-container)

Comment: nsenter tool is another approach to enter in a container, without requiring SSH server installation: https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter.
But this approach requires an access to your Docker host (usually SSH access is enough).

Comment: The link https://docs.docker.com/sorry/#/examples/running_ssh_service/ does not work. Can you please update it?

Answer (score 0):

if you can not change docker file /docker image.
here is the workaround:

docker run imageid   bash -c 'service mysql start ; while true ; do sleep 100; done; '

Answer (score 0):

I am using `docker-compose.yml` (version: "3.9")

What I do is add a command like below in the service of `docker-compose.yml` to start a service and running a non-end process.

```
command: /bin/sh -c "service mysql start; while sleep 1000; do :; done"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just been I trying and searching for hours before I found this hint here. I have tweaked the above:

- CMD: `'/bin/sh' '-c' '/mypath/startup.sh; bash'`
- "mypath" is on a persistent volume, where I placed startup.sh

In Portainer (2.11.1) this is placed in "Command", "Entrypoint" is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to run your main process as pid 1 but you also let say want to have cron started or some other service you may add something like

```
#make sure some other service starts on container start, tested in Ubuntu 20.04 based container
RUN echo "cron" >> /etc/bash.bashrc

CMD ["myproc"] #should run as 1 to receive sigterm
```

Using that approach chances are high, but didn't test it you could do something like, to start a service besides main process

```
RUN echo "service mysql start" >> /etc/bash.bashrc

CMD ["myproc"] #should run as 1 to receive sigterm
```

So basically you add custom entry to `/etc/bash.bashrc` and this is executed on system (container) start. Again Ubuntu 20.04, on other version the system `bashrc` may be under different name