# How to start mysql server in docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I am creating docker container and base image is ubuntu:14.04. I have to start mysql server in that container and then I have to create databases and I have to give the permission to the users. Docker is new for me. I tried a lot but still whenever I go to that image and check for mysql server is running or not. Every time what I got is mysql server is stopped and my dbs are also not created.
This is my dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER <name> <emailid>
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get install -y apache2 mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql php5 git
RUN sudo apt-get install -y vim
CMD sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld -u mysql
```

I tried a lot but i am not able to run mysql server in docker image.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions described on the official [MySQL](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) docker hub page?

Comment: I am not getting. I installed mysql in the container, then I did CMD sudo service mysql restart, then why its not starting sql server. I followed "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135897/how-to-automatically-start-a-service-when-running-a-docker-container" also, still same.

Comment: Did you read the Docker User Guide? What ever is started with CMD must be a process that is running continuously, e.g.: "while true; do date; sleep 10; done", or "/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND", or "/usr/sbin/mysqld -u mysql". Simply running "service mysqld restart" will just restart the service and then return, so the docker container stops.

Comment: mgor, I did this, still mysql is not running.

Comment: Share your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 24):

Did you manually install it in your container?

Why do you not simply use:

```
docker run -d --name mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret -e MYSQL_DATABASE=mySchema mysql:5
```

That would start a container named *mysql* running a mysql daemon, setting the default root password to *secret*, creating a new schema called *mySchema* and expose the MySQL port 3306 to clients so that they could connect.

Then you could connect to that with any MySQL client using the root user with the specified password *secret* and create your tables within the created schema *mySchema*.

Comment: I tried this also, It got stuck here
150810 11:43:38 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
150810 11:43:38 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
150810 11:43:38 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
150810 11:43:38 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.45'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: Did you try to connect to it? It says *ready for connections*

Comment: Why do I create a new container. I have to create an image in which this is required and then after I have to deploy that image. Is this not possible to start sql and create db and other stuffs at the time of creating that image.

Comment: Because in the *container instance* you will have the running MySQL daemon process. The image only contains *the files* on disk (like a tar archive).

Comment: Can you please give me your mailId, So that I will chat with you regarding my problem.

Comment: Even though if I did this, then that mysql daemon is running on my local machine, How the deployed image will communicate?

Comment: Does the Database always needed to be created?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue for ubuntu :14.04 while setting up druid cluster in the docker container, using CMD to start mysql fixed it for me.

CMD mysql start \

### Druid related stuff

```
&& mysql stop
```

Answer (score 2):

`docker exec -it container_name/id bash` 
`service mysql status` to check on the service status 
`service mysql start` to start the mysql service

Comment: Services in docker? There are no background processes in docker, that's part of its architecture