# How to build a Docker container with a running MySQL?

Tags: mysql, docker

My goal is to have a docker container that has a running MySQL service. So each time when I start container the database is in the initial state and MySQL is running.
Almost everything is fine but when I start the container the MySQL service is not running. Every time in the console I have to start it like this: service mysql start.
Here are the steps how I build and run the container:

```
$ docker build -t executer:mysql .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 15.87 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM debian:wheezy
#
# ... Many steps without error
#
Step 17 : RUN mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr/ --ldata=/var/lib/mysql/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1c71bf4524f0
Step 18 : RUN service mysql start
 ---> Running in b4643765b79b

......
MySQL Community Server 5.6.24 is started.
 ---> ac26b749a3c0
Removing intermediate container b4643765b79b
Successfully built ac26b749a3c0 

$ docker run --rm -it executer:mysql /bin/bash
root@1d9208c19af0:/# mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Cant connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
root@1d9208c19af0:/# service mysql start
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
......
[info] MySQL Community Server 5.6.24 is started.
root@1d9208c19af0:/# mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 5.6.24 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

And here is the content of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:wheezy

# add our user and group first to make sure their IDs get assigned consistently, regardless of whatever dependencies get added
RUN groupadd -r mysql && useradd -r -g mysql mysql

# FATAL ERROR: please install the following Perl modules before executing /usr/local/mysql/scripts/mysql_install_db:
# File::Basename
# File::Copy
# Sys::Hostname
# Data::Dumper
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y perl --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# gpg: key 5072E1F5: public key "MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>" imported
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys A4A9406876FCBD3C456770C88C718D3B5072E1F5

ENV MYSQL_MAJOR 5.6
ENV MYSQL_VERSION 5.6.24

RUN echo "deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ wheezy mysql-${MYSQL_MAJOR}" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list

# the "/var/lib/mysql" stuff here is because the mysql-server postinst doesn't have an explicit way to disable the mysql_install_db codepath besides having a database already "configured" (ie, stuff in /var/lib/mysql/mysql)
# also, we set debconf keys to make APT a little quieter
RUN { \
        echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/data-dir select ''; \
        echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/root-pass password ''; \
        echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/re-root-pass password ''; \
        echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/remove-test-db select false; \
    } | debconf-set-selections \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-server="${MYSQL_VERSION}"* && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/mysql && mkdir -p /var/lib/mysql

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y procps

# comment out a few problematic configuration values
RUN sed -Ei 's/^(bind-address|log)/#&/' /etc/mysql/my.cnf

# VOLUME /var/lib/mysql
# Install database
ADD ./database.sql /var/db/database.sql

# Set Standard settings
ENV user student
ENV password secret
ENV url file:/var/db/database.sql
ENV right READ

# Install starting script
ADD ./start-database.sh /usr/local/bin/start-database.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-database.sh

#EXPOSE 3306

RUN mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr/ --ldata=/var/lib/mysql/

RUN service mysql start
```

How should I change my Dockerfile to have a running MySQL service after running my container?

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25150809/1309035
`RUN` is during build time, `CMD` is during run time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically start a service when running a docker container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135897/how-to-automatically-start-a-service-when-running-a-docker-container)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your setup

see https://github.com/BITPlan/docker-stackoverflowanswers/tree/master/33299303

first I got

```
E: Version '5.6.24*' for 'mysql-server' was not found
```

which has nothing to do with your question but needs to be fixed.
so i commented out most of your Dockerfile and added:

```
RUN apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
```

which gave:
    E: Unable to locate package mysql-server-5.5

this is distro specific so i changed the FROM line to

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
```

which I am more familiar with

Then i modified the Dockerfile to change

```
RUN service mysql start
```

to

```
CMD service mysql start
```

as mentioned in the comment of michaelbahr and checked with

```
./run
```

and

```
root@96ff34b4e0c0:/# service --status-all 2>&1 | grep mysql
```

showed:

```
[ ? ]  mysql
```

there you are - mysql runs.
You might want to fix your Dockerfile accordingly.

Comment: For me this solution introduced another problem. During the install I have to provide the password.
But I could fix it like this:
`RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install mysql-server`

Comment: You can also set the noninteractive frontend via `ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive` at the top of your Dockerfile

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is to use MySQL docker image :
https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

All you have to do is:

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag
```

where:

- `some-mysql` is the name you want to assign to your container
- `my-secret-pw` is the password to be set for the MySQL root user
- `tag` is the tag specifying the MySQL version