# Docker Error when Starting an Image

Tags: docker

I have the following Dockerfile that is supposed to start nginx server:

```
# Set the base image to Ubuntu
FROM ubuntu

# File Author / Maintainer
MAINTAINER myname "myemail@gemail.com"

# Install Nginx

# Add application repository URL to the default sources
# RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

# Update the repository
RUN apt-get update

# Install necessary tools
RUN apt-get install -y nano wget dialog net-tools

# Download and Install Nginx
RUN apt-get install -y nginx  

# Remove the default Nginx configuration file
RUN rm -v /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Copy a configuration file from the current directory
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

# Append "daemon off;" to the configuration file
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 80

# Set the default command to execute when creating a new container
CMD service nginx start
```

When I tried to start the image that I created using docker build, I get the following error:

```
my-MacBook-Pro:nginx-docker me$ docker run -it myname:nginx-latest
2016-07-15T12:57:00.525640076+02:00 container create 0220107a0060cf61ff7dcb601870086b4ae7a0b7cacd914d63719e9a3d0d9451 (image=myname:nginx-latest, name=sad_knuth)
2016-07-15T12:57:00.542025710+02:00 container attach 0220107a0060cf61ff7dcb601870086b4ae7a0b7cacd914d63719e9a3d0d9451 (image=myname:nginx-latest, name=sad_knuth)
                                                                                                                                                                 2016-07-15T12:57:00.573835719+02:00 network connect 5e0b48e45380f1548ab524cfa7bfe94ae952ce740df76fda9e35561a258e31ef (container=0220107a0060cf61ff7dcb601870086b4ae7a0b7cacd914d63719e9a3d0d9451, name=bridge, type=bridge)
                  2016-07-15T12:57:00.654772110+02:00 container start 0220107a0060cf61ff7dcb601870086b4ae7a0b7cacd914d63719e9a3d0d9451 (image=myname:nginx-latest, name=sad_knuth)
                                                                                                                                                                                  2016-07-15T12:57:00.656973139+02:00 container resize 0220107a0060cf61ff7dcb601870086b4ae7a0b7cacd914d63719e9a3d0d9451 (height=42, image=myname:nginx-latest, name=sad_knuth, width=181)
                                                                                                                                                                                     * Starting nginx nginx                                                                                                                                                        [fail]
2016-07-15T12:57:00.715136152+02:00 container die 0220107a0060cf61ff7dcb601870086b4ae7a0b7cacd914d63719e9a3d0d9451 (exitCode=1, image=myname:nginx-latest, name=sad_knuth)
                                                                                                                                                                          2016-07-15T12:57:00.757891577+02:00 network disconnect 5e0b48e45380f1548ab524cfa7bfe94ae952ce740df76fda9e35561a258e31ef (container=0220107a0060cf61ff7dcb601870086b4ae7a0b7cacd914d63719e9a3d0d9451, name=bridge, type=bridge)
my-MacBook-Pro:nginx-docker me$
```

EDIT:

I even tried the following as per the recommendations:

```
myname-MacBook-Pro:nginx-docker me$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
0220107a0060        myname:nginx-latest   "/bin/sh -c 'service "   8 minutes ago       Exited (1) 8 minutes ago                        sad_knuth
7252213512f0        myname:nginx-latest   "/bin/sh -c 'service "   23 minutes ago      Exited (1) 23 minutes ago                       clever_jennings
53a5e6978978        myname:nginx-latest   "/bin/sh -c 'service "   25 minutes ago      Exited (1) 25 minutes ago                       gigantic_dubinsky
10fc9e4b749f        myname:nginx-latest   "/bin/sh -c 'service "   27 minutes ago      Exited (1) 27 minutes ago                       distracted_almeida
64161feb2b2a        0d73419e8da9          "nginx -g 'daemon off"   3 hours ago         Exited (1) 3 hours ago                          pensive_mcnulty
5c9eab4c7998        hello-world           "/hello"                 4 hours ago         Exited (0) 4 hours ago                          sharp_kare
myname-MacBook-Pro:nginx-docker me$ docker container 0220107a0060
docker: 'container' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'.
myname-MacBook-Pro:nginx-docker me$ docker logs 0220107a0060
 * Starting nginx nginx                                                                                                                                                       [fail]
```

Comment: Can you try this: Type `docker ps -a`, it will show the container in exited status. Then do `docker logs <containerID>`. Can you post the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMD service nginx start means the main process exits immediatly after launching nginx.

You would need

```
CMD /usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

To make sure it is not launched in daemon mode.
[Other alternatives are here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25135897/6309), but I prefer this one as it limits the number of processes to just nginx.