# mysqld service is not starting on docker run

Tags: docker

I am using the below command in the `dockerfile` to automatically start `mysql` on `docker run`:

```
ENTRYPOINT service mysql start && bash
```

The above command is working fine in some system but not in all. I also have tried the below command but still facing the same issue.

```
EXPOSE 3306
CMD /etc/init.d/mysql start && \
    /bin/bash
```

I am getting the below error in some system:

```
* Starting MySQL database server mysqld                             [fail]
```

So can anyone please help me solve this issue. So that my docker container can run on all type of system where docker can be installed.

Answer (score 0):

First, it depends on your exact `docker run` command.
As [commented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135897/how-to-automatically-start-a-service-when-running-a-docker-container#comment53268473_32179054), you approach works with `docker run -itd ...`

Second, it depends on the host, which should be compatible with docker execution (ie, its kernel should be the right architecture, 64bits not 32, recent enough...)

The OP adds:

> I am using `docker run -it docker_image_name command` to run the docker image and second system i.e. Linux corona2 4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 12 21:23:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux its not working.
>
> I have used 1.8.3 version to build my image and.
> is it because of the community edition version as ce is written with 18.03.1-ce.

Then yes: make sure to use the same docker version for building and running (on both servers)

Comment: I have used the same docker run command in two 64 bits architecture system. But only in one system its working. Here is the __uname -a__ output for both the system `Linux CG-Lab 3.16.0-71-generic #92~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 12 23:31:46 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` `Linux corona2 4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 12 21:23:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` In first case, its working fine but in other its not.

Comment: What is your docker run command? And on the system which is not working, do you see any error message? What `docker ps -a` shows you?

Comment: I am using `docker run -it docker_image_name` command to run the docker image and second system i.e. `Linux corona2 4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 12 21:23:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` its not working. I have added the error message in the question.

Comment: @Arijit What a `docker logs` of the container shows you? And what version of docker are you using?

Comment: docker logs showing the same error as I mentioned in the question. In `Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40`,  my docker image is **not running** but in `Docker version 1.8.3, build f4bf5c7`, it's **running**

Comment: @Arijit 1.8.3 seems very old compared to 18.03... Is it a typo?

Comment: it's not typing mistake. I have used 1.8.3 version to build my image. is it because of the community edition version as `ce` is written with 18.03.1-ce.

Comment: I tried to ran my docker image on another system where the system version is  `Linux STlab 4.13.0-43-generic #48~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 17 12:56:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` and docker version `Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40`. My docker image is working fine without showing any error. That's why I feel the docker community edition version is not the issue.

Comment: @Arijit OK, I didn't realize that when reading your original question. Compare their PATH and environment variable: there should be a difference which can explain that.

Comment: I compared both but could not find any reason. This has become a strange issue for me. I have also installed same os and same docker version on another system. On the new system, my container is working fine.