# How to add SSH access to a docker container

Tags: linux, docker, ssh

I have the following DOCKER FILE

```
FROM alpine:3.10 as builder

ARG VERSION=7.12.0
ARG DISTRO=tomcat
ARG SNAPSHOT=true

ARG EE=false
ARG USER
ARG PASSWORD

RUN apk add --no-cache \
        ca-certificates \
        maven \
        tar \
        wget \
        xmlstarlet

COPY settings.xml download.sh camunda-tomcat.sh camunda-wildfly.sh  /tmp/

RUN /tmp/download.sh

#Enable Basic AUTH
COPY web.xml /camunda/webapps/engine-rest/WEB-INF/web.xml 

##### FINAL IMAGE #####

FROM alpine:3.10

ARG VERSION=7.12.0



ENV CAMUNDA_VERSION=${VERSION}
ENV DB_DRIVER=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
ENV DB_URL=xx
ENV DB_USERNAME=dbname@xx
ENV DB_PASSWORD=xx
ENV DB_CONN_MAXACTIVE=20
ENV DB_CONN_MINIDLE=5
ENV DB_CONN_MAXIDLE=20
ENV DB_VALIDATE_ON_BORROW=true
ENV DB_VALIDATION_QUERY="SELECT 1"
ENV SKIP_DB_CONFIG=
ENV WAIT_FOR=
ENV WAIT_FOR_TIMEOUT=120
ENV TZ=UTC
ENV DEBUG=TRUE
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx768m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"

EXPOSE 8080 8000

# Downgrading wait-for-it is necessary until this PR is merged
# https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/pull/68
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        bash \
        ca-certificates \
        openjdk11-jre-headless \
        tzdata \
        tini \
        xmlstarlet \
    && wget -O  /usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh \
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/a454892f3c2ebbc22bd15e446415b8fcb7c1cfa4/wait-for-it.sh" --no-check-certificate \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh

RUN addgroup -g 1000 -S camunda && \
    adduser -u 1000 -S camunda -G camunda -h /camunda -s /bin/bash -D camunda
WORKDIR /camunda
USER camunda

#MSSQL SERVER JDBC DRIVER INSTALL
COPY mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre11.jar /camunda/lib/

ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--"]
CMD ["./camunda.sh"]

COPY --chown=camunda:camunda --from=builder /camunda .
```

This runs a CAMUNDA workflow Engine with an External SQL Paas Database and it works perfectly fine.
However in order to troubleshoot I need to be able to SSH into the container.

I found on this website how to do it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image

However the problem is that both ENTRYPOINT and CMD only allows ONE command, so I am not sure how to start up SSH

```
# ssh
ENV SSH_PASSWD "root:xyz"
RUN apt-get update \
        && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends dialog \
        && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssh-server \
    && echo "$SSH_PASSWD" | chpasswd 

COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/
COPY init.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/init.sh

EXPOSE 8000 2222

# end ssh config
```

Comment: have you considered ssh-ing to the host machine instead, then creating a shell into the container with `docker exec -it <your_container_id> /bin/bash`, instead ? Would that solve your problem ?

Otherwise, see [this doc page](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) that suggests using a custom script as CMD

Comment: this is running in Azure web app linux container, I dont have a way to do that

Comment: What are you needing to ssh into the container to do anyway? And you could start from the maven alpine images

Answer (score 4):

The Azure docs on this could be a bit better but you're almost there.

Firstly, since you're using Alpine Linux, your Dockerfile steps are a bit different from their example. Notably, you use `apk add` instead of `apt-get install`. Take a look at [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container#enable-ssh) which has examples of setting up SSH for Azure with Alpine.

```
RUN apk add openssh \
  && echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd
COPY ./path/to/sshd_config /etc/ssh/
```

The `sshd_config` should look something like this:

```
Port                    2222
ListenAddress           0.0.0.0
LoginGraceTime          180
X11Forwarding           yes
Ciphers                 aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
MACs                    hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
StrictModes             yes
SyslogFacility          DAEMON
PasswordAuthentication  yes
PermitEmptyPasswords    no
PermitRootLogin         yes
Subsystem               sftp internal-sftp
PidFile                 /etc/ssh/run/sshd.pid
HostKey                 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
```

The last step is to make sure that `sshd` gets started when the container starts up. While you're right that `CMD` can only take one command, that command can be a script which runs multiple things. By default, `sshd` forks a background process rather than running in the foreground so you should be ok. Your startup command could look like this for example:

```
#!/bin/sh

# ...

# Start sshd for Azure
ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -N '' -t rsa
mkdir -p /etc/ssh/run
/usr/sbin/sshd

# Run any additional commands like ./camunda.sh
```

Azure has some repositories with full sample projects including the SSH setup. Here's a [good example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/docker-django-webapp-linux) although it is Ubuntu and your container is Alpine so it's a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

- create a custom script that you will run at container startup ( `CMD` tag) that starts the `ssh` daemon and your other services
- (more hacky) [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135897/how-to-automatically-start-a-service-when-running-a-docker-container) simply put everything in your `CMD`