# What is Docker's ENTRYPOINT equivalent in an AMI?

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-ami, packer

How can I build an AMI using Packer that automatically launches an application (in my case an ASP.NET Core app).

I have done it in a docker image using `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "App.dll"]` but no idea how to do it in an AMI.

Comment: Use ECS with Windows_Server-ECS_Optimized https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_Windows_getting_started.html also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135897/how-to-automatically-start-a-service-when-running-a-docker-container

Comment: How are you launching the EC2 instance?